# How to use Groovy Eval

Tags: groovy

I have a string like the following:

```
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def request = slurper.parseText(dataRequest)
    def response1 = slurper.parseText(dataResponse)
    Eval.me('request.variable1 = request.variable2')
```

But I got an error: **javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "request" is not defined in  at line number 1**

Answer (score 0):

Use groovy expression like

```
def a = 2
def b = 3

Eval.me("$a == $b")
```

or use the xy method instead

```
Eval.xy(a, b, 'x == y')
```

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html